# Is there a way to treat a single column of integers as an array in order to extract certain digits?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I am trying to treat a series of integers as an array in order to extract the "columns" of interest.

My data after extracting a column of integers looks something like:

```
01010101010
10101010101
00100111100
10111100000
01011000100
```

If I'm only interested in the 1st, 4th, and 11th integers, I'd like the output to look like this:

```
010
101
000
110
010
```

This  problem is hard to describe in words, so I'm sorry for the lack of clarity. I've tried a number of suggestions, but many things such as awk's `substr()` are unable to skip positions (such as the 1st, 4th, and 11th positions here).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `cut` command:

```
cut -c 1,4,11 file
```

`-c` selects only characters.

or using (gnu) awk:

```
awk '{print $1 $4 $11}' FS= file
```

`FS` is the field separator which is set to nothing in order capture every single character.

Comment: `cut` is a good approach. The effect of setting FS to null is undefined behavior per POSIX so what that will do depends on the version of awk you are using.

Answer (score 4):

With GNU `awk` which can use empty string as field separator, you could do:

```
awk -F '' '{print $1, $4, $11}' OFS='' infile
```

Comment: It would be good if you could elaborat on this. (reference the standard)

Comment: He can't reference the standard because the effect of setting FS to null is undefined behavior per POSIX so what that will do depends on the version of awk you are using. He could reference the gawk user guide I suppose...

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following `awk` too.

```
awk '{print substr($0,1,1) substr($0,4,1) substr($0,11,1)}'  Input_file
```